# Como imprimir determinada lista a partir de uma string de um .csv usando python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A primeira parte que é detectar a posição da lista eu já consegui, o problema está na hora do **else**, gostaria de saber uma método com que faça que o else não seja impresso junto com o if.

Código e o "banco de dados" abaixo:

**Código**

```
def listar_critico():
arq = open("arquivo.csv", "r")
linhas = arq.readlines()
critico = input("Digite o nome do crítico que você deseja imprimir o registro..: ")
for linha in linhas:
    campos = linha.split(";")
    if critico in campos:
        print("\nCrítico: %s\nEmail: %s" % (campos[2], campos[3]))
    else:
        print("%s não está registrado no banco de dados." % critico)
arq.close()
```

Banco de Dados -> https://repl.it/Jbl1/5

[image]

Comment: Depende da estrutura do seu arquivo. O registro será único sempre, quando existir? Ou pode existir uma situação em que há mais de um registro para um mesmo crítico? Se interessar-te, o Python possui uma [biblioteca nativa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para se trabalhar com arquivos CSV.

Comment: O registro será único sempre, só quero salvar os críticos em algum .csv mesmo.
Irei ler mais sobre essa biblioteca, mas por enquanto eu quero fazer da maneira "primitiva" mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples que eu vejo para você é utilizar o `else` do `for` (sim, isso existe em Python).

O `else` do `for` é executado sempre que todo o laço é percorrido, ou seja, se o crítico não for encontrado nos registros. Mas quando for, você utiliza o `break` para interromper o laço.

Veja um exemplo:

```
import csv

critico = "Kenneth"

with open("data.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for data in reader:
        if critico in data:
            print(data)
            break
    else:
        print("{} não está registrado no banco de dados".format(critico))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/KBus/1).